# Why doesn't VLC play the videos?

Tags: vlc, video-player

I have a problem with ubuntu focal fossa. It often happens that when I click on a video (just to play it) VLC doesn't do anything, nothing happens, nothing appears. To let it work I have to restart my computer. What can be the problem?

Comment: You can run `vlc` through console and watch the output. It should tell You exactly why it can't play the video: `vlc [movie]`.

Comment: Dear @MichalPrzybylowicz, using the terminal it works. I can't understand why it doesn't without the terminal. It seems that the first time I try to play a movie it works. If i close vlc and than try to play a movie it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there anything printed in the terminal?

Comment: VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[000055a55d04c670] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/r600_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f46c4c0a530] avcodec decoder: Using Mesa Gallium driver 21.0.0-devel for AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-58-generic, LLVM 11.0.0) for hardware decoding

Comment: Next time this happens open system monitor and see if an instance of vlc is still running. Sounds like vlc isn't completely closing at these times..

Comment: @doug you are right! It does like you said. So, how do you think I can manage it?

Comment: Not sure you can solve this in a question & direct answer venue but for starters try deleting vlc's config. To do so delete the  ~/.config/vlc folder.

Comment: Dear @doug, I tried to delete vlc's config; at the beginning it seemed working but eventually not... Thank you for your help. If you have any suggestions that a beginner like me can follow, they are welcomed of course!